# Transferring event Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

My grandson has caught 15 or so of the event pokemon and it won't let me transfer them. How can I get rid of some of these?

Answer (score 11):

You cannot transfer them by selecting them, you have to transfer them one by one. That is done by:

- going to the individual Pokemon
- press the menu on the lower right
- pick transfer
- confirm twice (once more than normal, because of event/special Pokemon)

Answer (score 10):

In v0.173 (iOS), you can now mass transfer event Pokémon. To do so, do the standard method to mass transfer and select one. If you have an event Pokémon in your selection, you will be given a warning

[image: Mass transfer event]

---

The ability to bulk transfer holiday Pokémon was removed in update [Android 0.77.1 and iOS 1.47.1](https://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-100717/) along with additional confirmation to ensure you want to transfer them.

> - A confirmation dialogue now appears when attempting to transfer costumed Pokémon.
> - Costumed Pokémon can no longer be mass-transferred.

These Pokémon must be transferred on a one-by-one basis by clicking on the menu icon on the bottom and choose "transfer"